# How would I get the current time in ASM using GetSystemTime?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm, systemtime

Today I'm solving this problem in assembly lang: "Output the time and date using the GetSystemTime function.
Output format:

```
Date: 22 вересня 2007 року
Time: 17:05:35
Day of the week: Thursday
```

Pay attention to the time zone and indents in the text"

The problem is that when the data is displayed on the screen, the time is 3 hours behind the current time.

Answer who knows how to display the current time without using "GetLocalTime"? function

.inc File

```
include WINDOWS.inc

include user32.inc
include kernel32.inc

includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib

.data
    Time_title  db ' Lab_2',0
    FORMAT_STRING  \
    db '    system time:',0dh,0ah,0dh,0ah
    db '                 Date:       %ld %s %ld ðîêó',0dh,0ah
    db '                 Time:       %ld : %ld : %ld',0dh,0ah
    db '                 Day of the week:    %s',0dh,0ah
    db 0

    Month_ \
    db  'грудня',4 dup(0),\ 
        'січеня',5 dup(0),\
        'лютого',4 dup(0),\
        'березня', 3 dup(0),\
        'квітня',4 dup(0),\
        'травня',4 dup(0),\
        'червяня',4 dup(0),\
        'липня',5 dup(0),\
        'серпня',4 dup(0),\
        'вересеня',3 dup(0),\
        'жовтня',4 dup(0),\
        'листопадв',0
    
    Day_of_week \
    db  'Неділя',4 dup(0),\
        'Понеділок',0,\
        'Вівторок',2 dup(0),\
        'Середа',4 dup(0),\
        'Четвер',3 dup(0),\
        "П'ятниця",2 dup(0),\
        'Субота',0


.data?
    Save_esp dd ?
```

.asm File

```
.386
.model flat,STDCALL
option casemap :none  ;case sensitive
include Second.inc
include RADbg.inc

.code
Begin:
    call main
    invoke ExitProcess,NULL

main proc
LOCAL Time:SYSTEMTIME
LOCAL Buf[100]:BYTE
    mov Save_esp,esp
    invoke GetSystemTime,addr Time;
    xor eax,eax ; eax=0
    mov ax,Time.wDayOfWeek
    mov bx,10
    mul bx  ;ax*bx
    add eax,offset Day_of_week ;eax=address Day_of_week[Time.wDayOfWeek*10]
    push eax
    xor eax,eax 
    mov ax,Time.wSecond 
    push eax
    mov ax,Time.wMinute 
    push eax
    mov ax,Time.wHour   
    push eax
    mov ax,Time.wYear
    push eax
    mov ax,Time.wMonth
    mul bx
    add eax,offset Month_ ;eax=address Day_of_week[Time.wDayOfWeek*10]
    push eax
    xor eax,eax 
    mov ax,Time.wDay    
    push eax
    push offset FORMAT_STRING
    lea eax,Buf
    push eax
    call wsprintf
    mov esp, Save_esp
    invoke MessageBox,NULL,addr Buf,addr Time_title,MB_OKCANCEL
    ret
main endp   
end Begin
```

Comment: Is this homework and you can't just call the correct function?

Comment: @Anders, yes. It's my homework and teacher said that I can't using "GetLocalTime", only ''GetSystemTime'